# jQuery - работа с select

Tags: jquery, select2

Правильно ли я осуществляю работу с `select`:

```
var color_section_id = tabs_first_div.attr('data-color');
$('#select_body_item_' + color_section_id + 'option[value=0]').attr('selected', 'selected');
var select_body_item = $('#select_body_item_' + color_section_id + 'option:selected');
var select_body_item_value = select_body_item.text();
alert(select_body_item_value);
```

Выводит пустоту `alert`, а должен вывести "Выберите" в `option[value=0]` находится текст "Выберите".

Comment: вам как минимум перед каждым `option` надо поставить пробел потому, что в итоге получается что-то типа `$(#select_body_item_1option[value=0])`

Comment: Алексей, спасибо! Так и есть. Впервые работаю с конструкцией, когда складывается переменная с селекторами